# Setting up pre-installed mobile broadband in ubuntu 20.04 in thinkpad x1-carbon

Tags: networking, 20.04, lenovo, thinkpad, mobile-broadband

I have a `quectel em120r-gl 4g lte cat12` card already put in the computer. It came with windows 10 preinstalled and this card is working perfectly, I could see a mobile broadband connection option in setting and network options also. I just installed ubuntu and I am not able to find that here. I tried to check `additional drivers` but got nothing. I also tried `mmcli -L` and I am getting `No modem found` as response. Is anyone using the preinstalled modem in ubuntu thinkpad x1c gen 9 successfully? I am not even sure if I should continue looking for solutions or is it not possible?

Here is some more response:

```
~ ❯ lspci                                                                                                                                                                                                 11:49:51
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a14 (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a49 (rev 01)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a03 (rev 01)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a09 (rev 01)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a25 (rev 01)
00:07.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a27 (rev 01)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 9a11 (rev 01)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a0d (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a13 (rev 01)
00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a1b (rev 01)
00:0d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a1d (rev 01)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a0ed (rev 20)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device a0ef (rev 20)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device a0f0 (rev 20)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0e8 (rev 20)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a0e0 (rev 20)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device a0e3 (rev 20)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0b8 (rev 20)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a082 (rev 20)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a0c8 (rev 20)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device a0a3 (rev 20)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0a4 (rev 20)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a80a
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Device 1eac:1001

~ ❯ lsusb                                                                                                                                                                                                 11:49:54
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 13d3:5411 IMC Networks Integrated Camera
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 06cb:00fc Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: A little more information will be required to answer this question. Could you [edit] the post to include the Terminal output of `lsusb` and `lspci`. This will show some specific details about the hardware in your system 

Comment: @matigo I have added it.

Comment: https://forums.quectel.com/t/em120r-gl-for-linux/9350/4

Comment: [Looks like you'll need Kernel 5.13 or newer](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Fedora/Lenovo-X1-Gen-9-Fedora-and-Quectel-EM120R/m-p/5081326) to use the device with Ubuntu. Fortunately, Lenovo worked with Quectel to make it work. *Unfortunately*, this means you will need to either upgrade the kernel on your own or upgrade to the 21.10 interim release to use the modem ...

Comment: I had a problem with the same hardware and got it working with the same fcc unlock code. Some guidance: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414662/quectel-em120r-gl-modem-seems-to-work-but-sim-missing-or-not-detected/1414674#1414674