# Quectel EM120R_GL modem seems to work but SIM missing or not detected

Tags: networking, network-manager, modem

This card has two SIMs, SIM0 (or whatever number) and SIM1. SIM0 is eSIM and the default SIM, SIM1 is physical SIM inside the slot.  You need switch SIM0 to SIM1. This issue has been discussed before. I do not have experience with WWAN modems, but the modem itselfs seems to be properly detected and I inserted the SIM already. Still the `mmcli -m 1` says "sim-missing" and network manager shows:

[image]

Has someone experienced something similar before?

See some logs for my Ubuntu 22.04 below:

```bash
$ uname -a
Linux luminamdy 5.15.0-39-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 9 23:42:32 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ mmcli --list-modems
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1 [quectel] EM120R_GL

$ mmcli -m 1

  -----------------------------------
  General  |                    path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1
           |               device id: 259e11b87a3e93...
  -----------------------------------
  Hardware |            manufacturer: quectel
           |                   model: EM120R_GL
           |       firmware revision: EM120RGLAPR02A07M4G
           |          carrier config: ROW_Commercial
           | carrier config revision: 08010809
           |            h/w revision: EM120R_GL
           |               supported: gsm-umts, lte
           |                 current: gsm-umts, lte
           |            equipment id: 015930004772779
  -----------------------------------
  System   |                  device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.5/0000:04:00.0
           |                 drivers: mhi-pci-generic
           |                  plugin: quectel
           |            primary port: wwan0mbim0
           |                   ports: wwan0 (net), wwan0at0 (at), wwan0mbim0 (mbim), 
           |                          wwan0qcdm0 (qcdm)
  -----------------------------------
  Status   |                   state: failed
           |           failed reason: sim-missing
           |             power state: low
           |          signal quality: 0% (cached)
  -----------------------------------
  Modes    |               supported: allowed: 3g; preferred: none
           |                          allowed: 4g; preferred: none
           |                          allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                          allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 3g
           |                 current: allowed: any; preferred: none
  -----------------------------------
  Bands    |               supported: utran-1, utran-3, utran-4, utran-6, utran-5, utran-8, 
           |                          utran-2, eutran-1, eutran-2, eutran-3, eutran-4, eutran-5, eutran-7, 
           |                          eutran-8, eutran-12, eutran-13, eutran-14, eutran-17, eutran-18, 
           |                          eutran-19, eutran-20, eutran-25, eutran-26, eutran-28, eutran-29, 
           |                          eutran-30, eutran-32, eutran-38, eutran-39, eutran-40, eutran-41, 
           |                          eutran-42, eutran-43, eutran-46, eutran-48, eutran-66, utran-19
  -----------------------------------
  IP       |               supported: ipv4, ipv6, ipv4v6
  -----------------------------------
  SIM      |        primary sim path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/3
           |          sim slot paths: slot 1: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/2
           |                          slot 2: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/3 (active)

$ lsmod | grep wwan
mhi_wwan_mbim          16384  0
mhi_wwan_ctrl          20480  0
mhi                    94208  3 mhi_wwan_mbim,mhi_wwan_ctrl,mhi_pci_generic

$ nmcli device
DEVICE          TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION 
...
enp2s0f0        ethernet  unavailable             --         
wwan0mbim0      gsm       unavailable             --         
lo              loopback  unmanaged               --         
...

# use the listed device after "ifname":
$ nmcli c add type gsm ifname wwan0mbim0 con-name remoteConnection apn your-provider.something.com

# connect:
$ nmcli con up remoteConnection
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection (device enp2s0f0 not available because profile is not compatible with device (mismatching interface name)).

# delete:
$ nmcli con delete remoteConnection
```

Update:

> This card has two SIMs, SIM0 (or whatever number) and SIM1. SIM0 is eSIM and the default SIM, SIM1 is physical SIM inside the slot.  You need switch SIM0 to SIM1. This issue has been discussed before.

I think something like this is meant:

```
sudo mmcli -m 1 --set-primary-sim-slot=0
```

From https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Fedora/Lenovo-X1-Gen-9-Fedora-and-Quectel-EM120R/m-p/5081326?page=7

This worked and it shows now my SIM card, where I had to enter the PIN but it still don't let me connect with it... it gives me the following output in dmesg:

```
$ sudo dmesg |grep mhi
[    0.804861] mhi-pci-generic 0000:04:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xfd500000-0xfd500fff 64bit]
[    0.804879] mhi-pci-generic 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    0.805174] mhi mhi0: Requested to power ON
[    0.805796] mhi mhi0: Power on setup success
[    2.824741] mhi mhi0: Wait for device to enter SBL or Mission mode
```

But for `mmcli -m 1` it still shows `disabled`:

```
  Status   |          unlock retries: sim-pin (3), sim-pin2 (3)
           |                   state: disabled
           |             power state: low
           |          signal quality: 0% (cached)
```

Answer (score 2):

For those of you with `Lenovo Carbon X1 gen9` laptop.

As mentioned [here](https://forums.quectel.com/t/em120r-gl-for-linux/9350/7?u=arshia_akhavan), running the following script would automatically fix the problem for you

```bash
#! /bin/bash
# Download network-manager, modem-manager, etc.,...
sudo apt update
sudo apt install network-manager network-manager-gnome modemmanager libqmi-utils gcc
# Reference: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mobile-broadband/ModemManager/-/issues/402#note_1064882
mkdir -p ~/lenovo/snap
cd ~/lenovo
# Download the snap
snap download lenovo-wwan-dpr --edge
# Extract the snap files
sudo mount -t squashfs -o ro lenovo-wwan-dpr_13.snap /home/$(whoami)/lenovo/snap
# Download script by Joar Wandborg
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/joar/416f37fe81558f5be0d5131018eb7f2a/raw/b6a2a83620b044efc2d13aee86910743969218de/fcc-unlock.c
# TODO: manually modify the define statements in fcc_unlock.c appropriately
#define MBIM_DEVICE_PATH "/dev/wwan0mbim0"
#define MBIM2SAR_SO_PATH "/home/[username]/lenovo/snap/usr/lib/mbim2sar.so"
sed 's@#define MBIM_DEVICE_PATH \(.*\)$@#define MBIM_DEVICE_PATH "/dev/wwan0mbim0"@g' -i fcc-unlock.c
sed "s@#define MBIM2SAR_SO_PATH \(.*\)\$@#define MBIM2SAR_SO_PATH \"/home/$(whoami)/lenovo/snap/usr/lib/mbim2sar.so\"@g" -i fcc-unlock.c
# Compile the script
gcc -o fcc_unlock_v2 fcc-unlock.c
# Run the script
sudo env VERBOSE=1 ./fcc_unlock_v2 
mmcli -v --modem=`mmcli -L |head -n1 | awk '{print$1}'` -e
```

Answer (score 1):

The current situation is a mess. See yourself: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Fedora/Lenovo-X1-Gen-9-Fedora-and-Quectel-EM120R/m-p/5081326

The first step was to switch from the eSIM to the real SIM:

```
sudo mmcli -m 1 --set-primary-sim-slot=0
```

But the SIM still did not enable. It seems out that one has to unlock the device through some magic due to regulations. I compiled [this code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/joar/416f37fe81558f5be0d5131018eb7f2a/raw/b6a2a83620b044efc2d13aee86910743969218de/fcc-unlock.c) which was suggested [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mobile-broadband/ModemManager/-/issues/402#note_1064882).

But before I had to grab the mbim2sar.so file from the snap:

```
sudo snap download lenovo-wwan-dpr 
sudo mount -t squashfs -o ro /var/lib/snapd/snaps/lenovo-wwan-dpr_13.snap /home/user/snap/lenovo-wwan-dpr/13/
```

Now we can use:

```
#define MBIM2SAR_SO_PATH "/home/user/snap/lenovo-wwan-dpr/13/usr/lib/mbim2sar.so"
```

```bash
gcc fcc-unlock.c -o fcc-unlock
sudo env VERBOSE=1 ./fcc-unlock
```

As soon as I run the last command I was able to connect through the WWAN modem with my provider.

BUT it is VERY unstable. E.g. when I did a speed test the WWAN setting disappeared in the network manager and the connection dropped (as described in the forum). To re-enable it I have to do:

```
systemctl restart ModemManager.service
sudo env VERBOSE=1 ./fcc-unlock
```

**Update:** seems the author of the linked code below already did a similar step by step description [here](https://forums.quectel.com/t/em120r-gl-for-linux/9350/4).

Answer (score 0):

The complicated answers here are a bit out of date, as Lenovo has updated the official snap.

Install the snap, restart, and Mobile Broadband (in Settings) should Just Work(tm).

```
sudo snap install lenovo-wwan-dpr
```